# importxml xpath in Google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I need a some help in getting a ImportXML command to return the result I'm looking for. I'm using Google Sheets. This is the website: https://www.foresteu.com/butorajtok-es-tartozekaik/tomorfa/trieste/10000520000-tomorfa-trieste-116x146mm-mez

This xpath works, but it is way too long: `//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][2] | //div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][3] | //div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][4] | //div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][5] | //div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][6] | //div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')]/div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-120 nopad')][7]`

Can i make it shorter? I can't find a shorter xpath which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this xpath? I think that there might be more simple xpath. So please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Modified xpath:

```
//div[@class='col-xs-120 nopad'][./span]
```

- `https://www.foresteu.com/butorajtok-es-tartozekaik/tomorfa/trieste/10000520000-tomorfa-trieste-116x146mm-mez` is put in "A1".

  - Formula is `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='col-xs-120 nopad'][./span]")`
- `//div[@class='col-xs-120 nopad']` means `div` that `class` is `col-xs-120 nopad`.
- `[./span]` means `div` which have `span` under `div`.

#### Result:

[image]

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.